# What does acpi -t measure?

Tags: acpi

Whenever I use `acpi -t`, no matter what I'm doing, the temperature it displays is the same:

```
Thermal 0: ok, 14.0 degrees C
```

So to try and figure out why that is, I go to the man page:

> **acpi**  Shows  information from the /proc or the /sys filesystem, such as
>   battery status or thermal information.

This isn't that useful to someone like me who doesn't have a terribly in-depth understanding of the Linux kernel and whatnot, and the description of the `-t` option isn't any better:

```
   -t |  --thermal
             show thermal information
```

Can anyone explain what `acpi -t` is measuring to get it's information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) is an acronym for the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface. This interface is intended to be a standard way for the operating system to access information about the computer, including thermal info. The "thermal info" generally reports the temperature of the processor, although some systems may give additional info.

Evidently something between the sensor and the `acpi` command is not working properly, because the processor temperature should fluctuate with load and conditions.

Another tool is [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/), which uses different interfaces to read other sensor information from the computer.